# MATLAB GUI open m file

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I built some GUI in MATLAB with a pushbutton, and i want that when i click the pushbutton it will run some m script. 
I wrote in the pushbutton event function the name of the script like that:

```
function pushbutton1_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
scriptname
```

The problem is that when i click the pushbutton on the GUI window the GUI disappear and the m script runs

How can i do that the GUI will not disappear when i open some matlab script via the GUI?

Comment: First, check that you do not have a `close all` (or `close gcf`, or a comparable statement) in your script, which is closing the active window (your gui).

Comment: but i must close all the figures in my m script every time i run the script...(i make some image proccessing program so i need to close all the images in the figure windows)

Comment: Well, the recommended way would be to get rid of that `close all` statement (too generic for robust programming). I see 2 options: (1 _recommended_) In your script, keep the handle of all the new figure you generate, so when you need to close them you can close only the one you want. (2 _not really recommended_) Write a function which you plug on the `CloseRequestFcn` event of your main gui, so you can intercept the close request and dismiss it if not relevant. Be aware that this can yield funny behavior if not properly implemented (and check the `delete` function you'll need it).

Comment: what i did is to close all the specific figures and not to close all..i used in try and catch